# "using" syntax without braces works on some machines and not others - why?

Tags: c#, streamreader

this same line of code works on my colleagues PC but not mine. We both are using VS 2017 and not able to figure out why this is errors out for me.

[image]

I have read the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netcore-3.1

and I see that I need to use '(' and ')' but am baffled why it works on my colleagues PC.

Dependencies for this project are

[image: rea]

Comment: which c# version you use here?try `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))` or without using `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);`

Comment: As per @Sajid's comment .. you will need to have C#8 or higher to be able declare the StreamReader like this. Before c#8, this will not work. [Documentation on c# 8 changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations)

Comment: I have no clue why this was closed as needing clarity: it is entirely clear and meaningful....?

Comment: @MarcGravell just as how the vote was closed, there is a "reopen" link for *users* to nominate to reopen if they feel *its clear and meaningful*.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ the problem is: my votes are unilaterally binding. I therefore try not to be the only vote on any such decision. I can't vote: I can only make edicts

Comment: Thank you both @Sajid and ATJawad for the direction. C#8 was not installed so I had to without the 'using' scope. 

(Unfortunately I cannot add 2 users hence can't notify the second user's comment.)

Answer (score 4):

Your colleague has an up to date compiler. You do not. This ("using declarations" i.e. without the parens and braces) is one of the more recent additions - C# 8 IIRC.

The difference is old;

```cs
using (var x = {init}) {
  //...
}
```

versus new:

```
using var x = {init};
// ...
```

with the `using` scope implicitly lasting until the end of the *containing* scope (which many *do*, so this new syntax avoids a proliferation of indents and braces).

You should be able to update your compiler by installing the latest .NET Core SDK.